# Rails: Fetch model across many associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've tried wrapping my mind around how to navigate the associations I want, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to get all the `Posts` given a `Tag`. Each Post currently has a title and body text, both of which are represented as `TaggedText`. Each TaggedText can have many unique tags — like tagging multiple people/pages in a Facebook post (uniqueness is enforced in the model when saving an instance).

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_texts, through: :tag_ranges
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_texts
end
class TaggedText < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Each TaggedText cannot have more than one of each tag
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_ranges
  belongs_to :post
end
class TagRange < ActiveRecord::Base
  # TaggedText cannot have more than one of each tag
  belongs_to :tagged_text
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I tried joining the tables, but I get the error `Association named 'tag_ranges' was not found on Post`:

```
def get_posts_by_tag(tag, page, posts_per_page)
Post
  .joins(:tagged_texts)
  .joins(:tag_ranges)
  .joins(:tags)
  .where('tag.id = ?', tag.id)
  .uniq
  .limit(posts_per_page)
  .offset(page - 1)
  .to_a
end
```

What am I missing to get the query to work — or should I restructure my models and associations somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you error states, you need to add a `tag_ranges` association to your `Post` model. I've also added a few associations that you may or may not find useful, and one that will simplify your query greatly. Not that your `TagRange` class's associations are fine as is.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_ranges # need this association in order to get tagged_texts
  has_many :tagged_texts, through: :tag_ranges
  has_many :posts, -> { uniq }, through: :tagged_texts # posts with the given tag
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tagged_texts
  has_many :tag_ranges, through: :tagged_texts # Post now has association named 'tagged_ranges'
  has_many :tags, ->  { uniq }, through: :tag_ranges # tags that given post has
end

class TaggedText < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_ranges # all tag ranges for a tag text
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_range
  belongs_to :post
end
```

And now, your query to get all the posts for a tag:

```
def get_posts_by_tag(tag, page, posts_per_page)
  tag.posts.limit(posts_per_page).offset(page - 1).to_a
end
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly. Thanks Joe! Out of curiosity, what's the lambda doing: `-> { uniq }`? Is it just a 'hint' to the system, or is ActiveRecord actually enforcing something? I've never seen the lambda documented, could you find a link to its docs?

Comment: Also, in `Tag` you add the association `has_many :tag_ranges`, which apparently gets `tagged_texts` … Why does that association get `tagged_texts`, while the `has_many :tagged_texts, through: :tag_ranges` doesn't?

Comment: I haven't been able to find official documentation for `-> { }`, which is called a scope block, but you find some information about it in [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many). It's essentially defining a scope for you association. In this case it means when get this post's tag, only return the unique ones.

Comment: As for `has_many :tag_ranges`, my comment for that is a bit confusing, but what I meant is that without the `has_many :tag_ranges` line, you cannot use `has_many :tagged_texts, through: :tag_ranges`, because your tag object will have no idea what its `tag_ranges` are. Hopefully that's clearer now. Also note that I updated the `has_many :tags` line in the `Post` model, because it was `through: tagged_texts` when it should have been `through: tagged_ranges`, which it now is.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to help. And thank you for fixing my multiple syntax errors hahaha!